# Undefined variable: errors Lumen 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I got this error Undefined variable: error in Lumen 5.4

web.php

```
$app->get('/', 'SubscribersController@index');   
$app->post('/', 'SubscribersController@store');
```

controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:subscribers,email'
    ]);

    app('db')->table('subscribers')->insert([
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
    ]);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

index.blade.php

```
{{dd($errors)}}
```

So, how i can get my error? I can get error only in json format, but i want put this error on index.blade.php how this is possible?

```
{
  "email": [
    "The email must be a valid email address."
  ]
}
```

I want see this error in index.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

```
@if($errors->has())
   @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
      <div>{{ $error }}</div>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: ErrorException in 5b7696743b56fc2e549e96dcd8d99e342ce8f244.php line 52:
Undefined variable: errors

Answer (score 0):

[The lumen documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation) states that Lumen does not have the `$error` variable for views and that you should catch the error `$this->validate` throws. This way you can add the variables to your view manualy.

Comment: {{ dd($this->validate) }} say Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine::$validate

Comment: You should catch the exception in your controller

Comment: Okay, i catch my exception in my controller, how i can now send error to index.blade.php ? https://paste.laravel.io/7WY7n